# Subscribe EventEmmiter in an other service angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I try to test EventEmitter is correctly call in an angular service. But I have two service.

**Service One**

```ts
public methodToTestInServiceOne(message: string) {
  this.serviceTwo.methodInServiceTwo(message);
}
```

**Service Two**

```ts
public onMessageStart = new EventEmitter();
public onMessageEnd = new EventEmitter();

public methodInServiceTwo(message: string): void {
    this.onMessageStart.emit(message);
    /* Code... */
    this.onMessageEnd.emit(message);
  }
```

**Unit test Service One**

```ts
describe("serviceOne", (): void => {
  let serviceOne: ServiceOne;
  let serviceTwo: ServiceTwo;

  beforeEach((): void => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [] });
    service = TestBed.inject(ServiceOne);
    serviceTwo = TestBed.inject(ServiceTwo);
  });

  describe("methodToTestInServiceOne", (): void => {
    it("should call EventEmmiter", (): void => {
      let isMessageSend: boolean = false;

      serviceTwo.onMessageEnd.subscribe((message: string): void => {
        isMessageSend = true;
      });

      serviceOne.methodToTestInServiceOne("Hello World !");

      expect(isMessageSend).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

This code doesn't works, but if I called directly my service two.

```ts
serviceTwo.methodInServiceTwo("Hello World !")
```

The test works !
Please, how I can test my EventEmitter calling serviceOne ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `ServiceOne` and `ServiceTwo` in the `providers` array of the `TestBed`.

Try this:

```
describe("serviceOne", (): void => {
  let serviceOne: ServiceOne;
  let serviceTwo: ServiceTwo;

  beforeEach((): void => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      providers: [
        ServiceOne,
        ServiceTwo, // !! - Add these two here - !!
      ] 
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ServiceOne);
    serviceTwo = TestBed.inject(ServiceTwo);
  });

  describe("methodToTestInServiceOne", (done): void => { // !! add done here
    it("should call EventEmmiter", (): void => {
      let isMessageSend: boolean = false;

      serviceTwo.onMessageEnd.subscribe((message: string): void => {
        console.log(`1.) subscribing to message, ${message}`);
        console.log(`2.) Setting isMessageSend to true`);
        isMessageSend = true;
        done(); // !! call done to let Jasmine know we are done with the test
      });

      serviceOne.methodToTestInServiceOne("Hello World !");
      console.log(`3.) Checking isMessageSend is truthy`);
      expect(isMessageSend).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

```
public methodToTestInServiceOne(message: string) {
  console.log('[Service One] calling method in service two');
  this.serviceTwo.methodInServiceTwo(message);
}
....
public methodInServiceTwo(message: string): void {
    this.onMessageStart.emit(message);
    /* Code... */
    console.log('[Service Two] onMessageEnd being emitted');
    this.onMessageEnd.emit(message);
  }
```

Comment: I implemented the both service to the providers but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I have made some edits by adding `console.log`s. I am thinking the order can be off. Make sure you see `1.) ...` then `2.)..` then `3.)....`. If you see 3 then 1 then 2, that's a timing issue or you may see 3 but not 1 and 2 and that means the test never went inside of the `subscribe`.

Comment: I never see console.log 1 and 2. The subscribe is not called.
But when I call directly serviceTwo The subscribe is called and the timing is good

Comment: Check out the new console.logs and ensure you see them and also add the `done`. I am thinking it never goes inside of your subscribe. Maybe because it is an early `subscriber`.

Comment: Thank you AliF50 ! After test with last console.log's the subscriber it is okay and call in time. The problem came from my code...